# How get Telegram api chatid

Tags: telegram

How to get chat_id by phone number whithout telegram client. Like this: `https://api.telegram.org/bot111:2222222/sendContact?phone_number=+98919123`

Answer (score 0):

You will get `contact.user_id` in `result`.

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]

Comment: Could give me url link for get chatid by phone_number?